# Semi copy/clone constructor for update methods

Tags: scala

I have many case classes in the format of

```
case class Cluster (id: Pk[Long],
        foo: Long,
        bar: String,
        env: String,
        name: String,
        deleted: Boolean = false) {
    def delete() = Cluster(id, foo, bar, env, name, true)
    def updateName(name: String) = Cluster(id, foo, bar, env, name, deleted)
    def updateFoo(foo: Long) = Cluster(id, foo, bar, env, name, deleted)
}
```

I and trying to have all of my classes immutable, i.e. update methods are creating a new instance.
Some of the classes have many more members and having the update methods cloning the self object with a different value is tedies error prone.

Any ideas of how to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need your methods. You just need to:

```
val c1 = Cluster(...)
val c2 = c1.copy(env = "new env") // Just list those fields you want to update.
```

The copy() method is available on case classes "for free".

Comment: I didn't know you got copy for free.  That's awesome +1.